# How can I make a Bootstrap 3 navbar change from dropdowns to collapses when the navbar is collapsed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, navbar

I'm building a page with heavily tiered navigation and the boss wants the entirety of the navigational path to be accessible from every page whether it's viewed on a workstation or a mobile device. I figured out how to build menus that work well for each device type, but I can't figure out how to switch between them dynamically.

I'm trying to figure out how to change a dropdown menu like this,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
 <li>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MainHeader</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SubHeader</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">ListItem</a></li>
```

to a collapse menu like this,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
 <div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">MainHeader</a>
   </div>
   <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1a">SubHeader</a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1a" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">ListItem</a></li>
```

whenever the bootstrap navbar is collapsed.

p.s. This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm new to both CSS and Bootstrap so I'm sure I'll have to edit this question for clarity. I apologize in advance for any confusion I cause.

Comment: It would help if you created a demo on CodePen :)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but I found out that css media queries would allow me to trigger the behavior I wanted at the same viewport width as bootstrap uses to trigger the menu collapse.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #navbar-menu-collapse {
         display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #navbar-menu-dropdown {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

I made a codepen example that behaves the way I wanted, but if someone knows a better solution I would still be very interested!

http://codepen.io/LordGriffon/pen/peyRjZ